# Bookdown different even and odd pages margins with pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using bookdown package version 0.13 with R 3.6.0.

When I generate a pdf output, the even and odd pages have different margins. Even pages are shifted to the right and odd ones to the left (see picture below). Is this some type of feature? For example, for printing?

How can I disable this behavior?

[image]

I get the same margin differences when trying the minimal example provided in [the official demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo). The `_bookdown.yml` file has this content:

```
book_filename: "bookdown-demo"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "
delete_merged_file: true
new_session: yes
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What do you you have in the YAML header of your file?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the reproducible example and YAML contents.

Answer (score 6):

The margins are changed because by default the format is twoside. I fixed this by changing it to oneside. This was done by adding the following in index.Rmd

```
classoption: oneside
```

in latex this is specified with:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```

Comment: Thanks for spelling out that this option needs to be set in `index.Rmd` ... I spent hours  with `_bookdown.yml`. Now I need to find out how to control the margins for an A4 report!